# <f:ajax onerror> called on every ajax request even if completed

Tags: ajax, jsf, onerror

This simple piece of code makes an alert every time a change event happens in the spinner. However the ajax status says the request has been completed and doesn't notify an error.

```
<p:ajaxStatus/>   
<p:spinner value="#{testBean.number}"
    id="testSpinner" min="1" max="20">
    <f:ajax event="change" onerror="alert('error')"/>
</p:spinner>
```

---

The content of ajax status is this one :

```
<f:facet name="default">
    <h:outputText value="Status: StandBy" />
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="onerror">
    <h:outputText value="Status: onerror" />
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="complete">
    <h:outputText value="Status: Completed" />
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write something that return a function type for the onerror attribute. If you write a function call then this function is called in order to obtain a value, if this value was a function type there would be no problem, but `alert` function doesn't return any function type, moreover it generate the side efect of printing a message on the screen. So what you have to do is:

define the `myfunction` function:

```
<script>
    var myfunction = function(){alert('error')};
</script>
```

and then do:

```
<f:ajax event="change" onerror="myfunction"/>
```

**NOTE:**

Beware of not mixing up `<f:ajax ... />` and `<p:ajax ... />`. These two are equivalent:

```
<f:ajax onerror="function(){alert('ERROR')}" />
```

and

```
<p:ajax onerror="alert('ERROR')" />
```

Comment: Yeah this works but I'm not sure I quite understand the difference between writing alert('') directly and writing a var that is pointing to that function. Could you expand on that ?

Comment: A javascript function, i.e: `myfunction`, is a value that wraps a piece of logic. You execute this logic calling the function, i.e. `myfunction()`. JSF expects a value of type function for `onerror` attribute, so you have to write a variable of type function or, not the common, a function call only if the called function returns another function which will be call if an ajax error occurs.

Comment: This is also stated in vdldoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/ajax.html *"The name of the JavaScript function that will handle errors"*